# Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider'

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

After installing Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7, I get the following error when connecting to a server with SQL Management Studio:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider'. This
>   operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component
>   for the interface with IID '{6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA}'
>   failed due to the following error: No such interface supported
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>   (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop)

I've seen blog postings recommending reregistering actprxy.dll, but this has no effect.  Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm having a similar error when I try to publish with ClickOnce (no sql-server involved)

Answer (score 25):

actprxy.dll also didn't work for me. I found a solution that worked [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/d5d3e5fc-d8ce-4f42-b7ea-9bbbb7756a20/)

> regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"
>
> if you are running 64 bit windows, try this:
>
> regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"

Comment: I was running into this issue on the new (as of April 2012) Visual Studio 11 beta. Running this step fixed it for me. Thank you!

Comment: This solution fix the problem. And for those who don't have just in time debugging enabled, note that this fix some error reported as: microsoft visual studio has stopped working Maybe it will help others lose less time. Frederic

Comment: I had this error in Visual Studio (although it was not a new install, it came all of a sudden) and the first line fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

It's triggered when NPMWrapper tries to launch interactive auth.
Try

```
npm logout
```

then

```
npm login
```

this worked for me. Seems to be a bug in the [login sequence](https://github.com/LeCantaloop/Qwiq/issues/219)