# Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, publishing

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to publish an XNA project in Visual Studio 2010.

> Error 1   Publish failed with the following error: Unable to cast COM
>   object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider'. This operation
>   failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the
>   interface with IID '{6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA}' failed due
>   to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).     1   1   Asteroids

I've tried registering `actxprxy.dll` and `ieproxy.dll` as others have suggested, but I continue to get this error.

I get this error with a blank XNA Game template, as well as a completed XNA game.

I am able to Build and Debug the same projects fine.

Comment: Please share some code to discuss.

Comment: It's code irrelevant, occurs with other's code, my own, and just an entry method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a [discussion](http://msmvps.com/blogs/martinpoon/archive/2009/03/20/ssms-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-system-comobject-to-interface-type-microsoft-visualstudio-ole-interop-iserviceprovider-exception-from-hresult-0x80004002-e-nointerface.aspx) that claims that this is due to "registry corruption". One of the comments proposes a "nuclear" solution of re-registering every single OCX and DLL in the System32 folder:

```
for %1 in (%windir%\system32\*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %1
for %1 in (%windir%\system32\*.ocx) do regsvr32 /s %1
```

Perhaps it could solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654322/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-system-comobject-to-interface-type-micros?rq=1) suggested to register ieproxy.dll

> regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"
>
> if you are running 64 bit windows, try this:
>
> regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"