# How to publish an application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publish, solution-explorer

I created a sample application and i wanted to publish that application using 
the Visual Studio publish button in the solution explorer but when i do so i am getting the below error 
what must i do to avoid that?

> Error 1   Publish failed with the following error: Unable to cast COM
>   object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider'. This operation
>   failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the
>   interface with IID '{6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA}' failed due
>   to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the COM visibility if not required, as reported in this [msdn social post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/8756ef09-9c94-4a01-9d2d-44e1275ad810).

Right click the project, settings, application, assembly information, unmark make com visible.

Another approach is listed in [this post:](http://msmvps.com/blogs/martinpoon/archive/2009/03/20/ssms-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-system-comobject-to-interface-type-microsoft-visualstudio-ole-interop-iserviceprovider-exception-from-hresult-0x80004002-e-nointerface.aspx)

> After a bit of investigation, I found that the registry is somehow
>   corrupted, and the solution is to re-register DLL.
>
> ~ Run [ Command Prompt ] (You will need to use the **Run as
>   administrator** option)
>
> ~ regsvr32 actxprxy.dll

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an environment issue- try re- registering [actprxy.dll](http://computech.in/2011/01/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-system-__comobject-to-interface-typemicrosoft-visualstudio-ole-interop-iserviceprovider-this-operation-failed-because-the-queryinterface-call-on-the-com-componen/) and/or [ieproxy.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654322/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-system-comobject-to-interface-type-micros)