# Error message (E_NONINTERFACE) opening SQL Server 2008 R2 SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I get this error when trying to open SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider'. This
>   operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component
>   for the interface with IID '{6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA}'
>   failed due to the following error: No such interface supported
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>   (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop)

Details:

- Windows 7 Professional
- SQL Server 2008 R2
- Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Is this a brand new install?  Did something change recently on the PC?  Also, this is probably more relevant on [SU]

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem, after a lot of search on Google and tried a lot of different solution that didn't worked in my case, I finally find a working solution on another thread of stackoverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654322/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-system-comobject-to-interface-type-micros)) based on a [social.msdn thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/d5d3e5fc-d8ce-4f42-b7ea-9bbbb7756a20/). It seems that other solutions could work, depending on undefined situations as far as the problem cause isn't well defined...

The solution that worked for me:

> regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"

if you are running 64 bit windows, try this:

> regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"

The solution that worked for others:

> First deregister the dll:
>
> C:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe" /u actxprxy.dll

Then register it again: "C:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe" actxprxy.dll

Note: use a command shell in both case with administration rights (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then type cmd)

Answer (score 0):

Some information on Connect, though [Microsoft is saying they can't reproduce the problem](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/332524/title-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio).

Have you installed [SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26727) to your client machine? I would try that. It is possibly something messed up due to order of installation of SQL Server / Visual Studio. Applying the service pack should help straighten it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint, user1267600!
I've got the same issue, but in my case the problem was I've moved accidentally the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer" folder to another one and SSMS started showing this error. Then I've found it and moved it back and everything got back to working. No "ieproxy.dll" registration was needed.

*Hint - Don't move around the "Internet Explorer" folder or any other Windows related soft folder, you'll never know what depends on it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After installing IE11, I registered ieproxy.dll and SQL Server Management Studio is running again. Thanks!!!