# VS 2010 Ultimate: Attaching the ProteusDebugEngine debugger to process failed

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When loading a C# / .NET 4 project into VS 2010 Ultimate on my main machine (Win 7 ultimate 64 bits), I am getting the error message

```
Attaching the ProteusDebugEngine debugger to process '[XXXX] YYYY.vshost.exe'
on machine ZZZZ failed. The debugger is not properly installed. 
Cannot debug the requested type of code.
Run setup to install or repair the debugger.
```

This only happens when I set the target to 'Any CPU' or 'x64'; I don't get this message for a x86 target.

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled VS 2010 two times, and also have tried a repair. Manually re-registering oleaut32.dll does not help either.

When installing VS 2010 Ultimate on my notebook (Win 7 home premium 64 bits), I do not get this error message at all.

Both machines have a pretty similar software setup. There is also VS 2010 Express installed on both machines, and I do not get this error with it on any of the two computers either.

Help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I only got rid of this problem after reinstalling Windows 7. D'uh.

Comment: Installing VS11 beta also cause this error =/

Answer (score 1):

Recently I encountered this problem too, but in addition to it I also faced with another error message box showing up in SQL Server Management Studio when I tried to connect to a server, which says:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider' ...

so this time I googled for this error and found a solution which I found at below urls:

[Martin Poon - Microsoft MVP blog - Unable to cast COM object of type ...](http://msmvps.com/blogs/martinpoon/archive/2009/03/20/ssms-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-system-comobject-to-interface-type-microsoft-visualstudio-ole-interop-iserviceprovider-exception-from-hresult-0x80004002-e-nointerface.aspx)

[Stack Overflow - Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654322/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-system-comobject-to-interface-type-micros/3621696#3621696)

So it seems those problems happen when you have installed new version of Internet Explorer on your windows manually or using windows update.
in my case it's related to installing the IE9 using windows update on my Windows 7 x64 which has been resolved by following the instruction at above urls.

or in short:

```
open Command Prompt as Administrator and execute below command(s):

regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"

for 64 bit windows, also try this:
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"
```

and voila both problems just faded away :-)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same message popping up after I installed Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 on a new system. I had pulled the source from tfs and everything compiled. The configuration had been set to Any CPU for each project, however the setting up top was "Mixed", once I set the overall type to AnyCPU and cleaned the solution, it started fine in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following in the Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010) solved this for me.

```
devenv /resetskippkgs
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this helped:
1. Open preferences of the project
2. Unchecked "Prefer 32 bit" in Platform targets section from a build tab.