# ProteusDebugEngine Attaching the debugger to process '...' on machine '..' failed

Tags: visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VS 2010 Ultimate: Attaching the ProteusDebugEngine debugger to process failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627251/vs-2010-ultimate-attaching-the-proteusdebugengine-debugger-to-process-failed)

I installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on my computer (Windows 7 64) and I have all service packs updated.

When I open a solution I get the following error message:

"ProteusDebugEngine Attaching the debugger to process '[7872] PCT.Monitor.vshost.exe' on machine 'AR' failed. Invalid Pointer"

Where PCT.Monitor.vshost.exe is my application and 'AR' is the name of my computer.

The same error occurs when I define another project in my solution as "Startup Project".

Also I get the same error after stop debugging a project.

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you,

Alexandre Vianna